# How do I choose the right name to suggest English nobility or royalty?

Tags: names

I want to write a story with tight ties with England, and even with noble families.  What surname sounds more classy, purely ENGLISH, royal/noble sounding and posh? Stratford, Windsor, Gladstone, Prescott or Berkeley?  Why?

Comment: What period in England? Depending on the period you might have a mix of Anglo-Saxon, Norman, Scottish, Welsh, Irish, and Germanic names for royalty.

Comment: I predict this will get put on hold pretty quickly, because you've asked an opinion-based question.

If you want to know what the "Poshest" British name is, the present Queen of the UK is the richest woman on Earth (if you include real estate value.) That's relatively posh.  Her dynastic name is Windsor, but it's not strictly her "surname", and this is somewhat typical for nobility.

Comment: I think this is a very good question. Compare *Horatio Herbert Kitchener* and *Tommy Watkins* ... would Mrs. Watkins have come up with a Horatio?

Comment: Nobility intermarries culturally quite often (or did when feudalism ran the world, at least) for diplomatic and claim-acquiring purposes.  All that is required for a British noble to wind up with the name Horatio is to have one parent from a noble house of Spain.

Comment: But, the question is regarding surnames, anyway.  And the simplest answer is "none."  British nobility typically don't use surnames.  A noble introducing themselves as <firstname> <lastname> is probably trying to pass for a commoner.

Comment: @SudoSedWinifred The grand irony is the Queen is more Germanic than English and the [House of Windsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Windsor) is made up. George V changed it to Windsor from "Saxe-Coburg and Gotha" of the House of Wettin because it sounded too Germanic when WWI broke out.

Answer (score 3):

This question is really really broad and so I am just going to give you some links to check out

1. [Top surnames from an 1881 census](http://www.britishsurnames.co.uk/1881census/hampshire/whitchurch)
2. [100 most popular English surnames](http://www.rong-chang.com/namesdict/100_last_names.htm)
3. [A-Z English Family surnames](http://members.tripod.com/~Caryl_Williams/names-7.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best names that suggest English nobility are names of the actual nobility!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Noble_families_of_the_United_Kingdom

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of someone from the USA who watches British tv shows sometimes (which are typically police procedurals, mysteries, oe comedies):

- Use a multi-part name with hyphins.
- have extra letters that are not pronounced.
- suffix it with roman numerals and/or other decorations.
- don't use the terms "Mr./Mrs." but insist on some special title instead.

Shows that are light comedy in tone but primarily a drama, mystery, or whatever (not a "comedy") would be the best to observe to get a stereotypical name that deliberately conveys the social status and history of the guest character, without being overly silly about it.

Comment: I did not say *all* names had these features. I stated my observations that fiction draws upon these as stereotypes.

Comment: I thought about noting examples when I watched such shows, but the question was closed and I think writers’ forums have resources for choosing names already.